# Get route with parameter not working Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 8, and when I use a GET route with parameter {id}, it shows "undefined variable" in view.

#### Error message

```
Undefined variable $userdata (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\resources\views\profile.blade.php)
```

#### Route

```
Route::get("/profile/{id}", [UserController ::class,'showUserdata']);
```

#### Controller

```
function  showUserdata($id)
{
    id = User::find($id);
    $data = User::all()->where('id',$id;
    return  view ('profile', ['userdata' => $data]);
}
```

#### View

```
@foreach ($userdata as $key)
    <label>First Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname" value=" {{ $key->firstname }}"> <br>
    <label>Last Name</label> <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname" value="{{ $key->lastname }}"> <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Try this in your controller = 
`$data['userdata'] = User::all()->where('id',$id);]
return  view ('profile')->with($data);`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your query

```
 $data = User ::all()-> where('id',$id );
```

to

```
$userdata = User::where('id',$id )->get();
```

And you are sending data to the blade in a wrong way

```
`return  view ('profile',compact('userdata'));`
```

Comment: I tried all the above solutions, but still same problem. Same error

Comment: Did you rename the `$data to $userdata` ? @Ankur

Comment: Yes I tried, but still same error

Comment: Please share your update code from controller @Ankur

Comment: function showUserdata($id)
    {
        $userdata = User::where('id', $id)->get();
       return view('profile', compact('userdata'));
    }

Comment: Did you try to dump the data you are getting in that variable ? `dd($userdata);` ? @Ankur

Answer (score 0):

**The error is in view usage, not in other parts of your code. View is seen in your code as a function not a Model with functions!**

I use view in a different way like this:

```
View::make('profile',['userdata'=>$data])->render();
```

Please see the View::make where make is the function associated with the "model" View.

Answer (score 0):

There is some misstakes in your code, don't worry you will ge the hang of it. I have compiled an alternative for you that might be what you want.

#### Your previous code

```
function  showUserdata($id)
{
    id = User::find($id);
    $data = User::all()->where('id',$id;
    return  view ('profile', ['userdata' => $data]);
}
```

#### Change to this:

```
function  showUserdata($id)
{
    $data = User::find($id);
    return view('profile', ['userdata' => $data]);
}
```

### Another solution is to use route model binding.

```
use App\Models\User;

function showUserdata(User $User)
{
     return view('profile', ['userdata' => $user]);
}
```

And your `web.php` would look like:

```
Route::get("/profile/{user}", [UserController::class,'showUserdata']);
```